# Multiplcation of two dataframes with where condition on it

Tags: python, pandas

I have two df1 and df2

```
raw_data1 = {
            'dogs': [42, 39, 0, 15, 23, 0, 68, 81, 86],
            'cats': [52, 41, 79, 0, 34, 47, 19, 22, 0],
            'sheep': [62, 37, 0, 51, 67, 32, 0, 89, 73],
            }

raw_data2 = {
            'dogs': [42, 39, 0, 15, 23, 0, 68, 81, 86],
            'cats': [52, 41, 79, 0, 34, 47, 19, 22, 59],
            'sheep': [62, 37, 84, 51, 67, 0, 23, 89, 73],
            'lizards': [72, 43, 0, 26, 53, 88, 88, 34, 69],
            'birds': [82, 35, 77, 0, 18, 12, 45, 56, 0],
            }

df1 = pd.DataFrame(raw_data1,
                  index=pd.Index(['row_1', 'row_2', 'row_3', 'row_4', 'row_5', 'row_6', 'row_7', 'row_8', 'row_9'], name='Rows'),
                  columns=pd.Index(['dogs', 'cats', 'sheep'], name='animals'))

df2 = pd.DataFrame(raw_data2,
                  index=pd.Index(['row_1', 'row_2', 'row_3', 'row_4', 'row_5', 'row_6', 'row_7', 'row_8', 'row_9'], name='Rows'),
                  columns=pd.Index(['dogs', 'cats', 'sheep', 'lizards', 'birds'], name='animals'))
```

When I do the following code

```
df3 = (df2 * df1.loc['row_8'] * 10).where(df1 == 0)
```

I'm getting all 5 columns in df3 but I want only the column names which are in df1. How do we do multiply with respect to df1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`reindex_like`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_like.html) to ensure that the indexes of `df2` will be identical to that of `df1`:

```
(df2.reindex_like(df1) * df1.loc['row_8'] * 10).where(df1 == 0)
```

Or, slice the output with the columns of `df1`:

```
(df2 * df1.loc['row_8'] * 10).where(df1 == 0)[df1.columns]
```

output:

```
animals  dogs     cats    sheep
Rows                           
row_1     NaN      NaN      NaN
row_2     NaN      NaN      NaN
row_3     0.0      NaN  74760.0
row_4     NaN      0.0      NaN
row_5     NaN      NaN      NaN
row_6     0.0      NaN      NaN
row_7     NaN      NaN  20470.0
row_8     NaN      NaN      NaN
row_9     NaN  12980.0      NaN
```

You can also prefilter:

```py
df2.loc[:, df1.columns].mul(df1.loc['row_8'] * 10).where(df1 == 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `Index.intersection` method:

```
df3 = (df2[df2.columns.intersection(df1.columns)] * df1.loc['row_8'] * 10).where(df1 == 0)
```

Output:

```
animals  dogs     cats    sheep
Rows                           
row_1     NaN      NaN      NaN
row_2     NaN      NaN      NaN
row_3     0.0      NaN  74760.0
row_4     NaN      0.0      NaN
row_5     NaN      NaN      NaN
row_6     0.0      NaN      NaN
row_7     NaN      NaN  20470.0
row_8     NaN      NaN      NaN
row_9     NaN  12980.0      NaN
```